# Articles from Joomla website to appear in a non joomla website

Tags: php, joomla, joomla3.0

here's my problem. I got a joomla website that is used only locally in my company. I get to do functions like create articles,post downloads, etc. It runs fine but my boss wants the articles/downloads created in joomla to appear in a different website which my boss made. not i'm not sure if it can be done or i would need to use a php code to access my joomla database.

Comment: Yes you need to write some php code and get assess to joomla database with this code.

Comment: You need to ask a specific *programming* question. This is far too broad to answer clearly.

Comment: ok, what code could i insert in the non joomla website in order for me to access the joomla database where the articles are stored?

Comment: You could export your content to an rss feed and add to your remote site an rss reader to get this content directly from your site.

Comment: I see.. but what I want to achieve is to get the article and when the user clicks the link.. it will open into a webpage with the non-joomla's website look and not my joomla website's look.

Comment: You develop an API(group of functions) on your Joomla site those will return or submit data accordingly. These group of functions also called Webservices. As i have did this for providing data(From Joomla DB) to Mobile apps.

Comment: Write connect to your external database, write a database query to fetch the articles, display the results. Please do some research and provide some code/methods that you have already tried else this question will most likely be downvoted and closed

Answer (score 0):

There's a "content" table in Joomla database, where all articles are stored. It has pretty clear structure: id, title, alias, introtext, fulltext... etc. Just use a simple "SELECT * FROM content" query and get articles array. After that you can do with it anything you want.